# $_FILE upload large file gives error 1 even though upload_max_size is bigger than the file size

Tags: php, file, upload, size

I have a simple upload form with:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
```

and

```
input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5900000" />
```

And the following settings, that are applied (checked through phpini()) in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 7MB  
memory_limit = 64M  
post_max_size = 8MB
```

I try to upload a file that is small - 500k and it goes through

I try to upload a file that is 5MB (smaller than both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings) and it fails with error code 1: which says is:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>   Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Anyone has a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think this is because of a typo. Instead of

```
upload_max_filesize = 7MB
```

it should read

```
upload_max_filesize = 7M
```

use `phpinfo()` again to check what value actually gets applied.

Comment: You'r right, that solved the problem. The trick I didn't realize was that phpinfo() does show 7MB value, but it doesn't consider it appropriate. it's all good now, luv ya

Answer (score 8):

---

You also have to set the `post_max_size` in "php.ini"

Answer (score 5):

```
upload_max_filesize = 7M
```

Here the value is like `7M` or `10M` but not `MB`.

Use `phpinfo()` again to check what value actually got applied.

Use the code below to understand what the problem is. If file size is the problem, it simply prints out put as exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in `php.ini`

```
<?php
$error_types = array(
    1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.',
    'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.',
    'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.',
    'No file was uploaded.',
    6 => 'Missing a temporary folder.',
    'Failed to write file to disk.',
    'A PHP extension stopped the file upload.'
);

// Outside a loop...
if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0) {
    // here userfile is the name
    // i.e(<input type="file" name="*userfile*" size="30" id="userfile">
    echo "no error ";
} else {
    $error_message = $error_types[$_FILES['userfile']['error']];
    echo $error_message;
}
?>
```

By this we can easily identify the problem. We can also use `switch(){ case }` to print the above error messages.

Comment: Just wanted to note the link to the php docs for error codes and messages: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 3):

Here is a big mistake I've done:

If you want to upload really big files, you have to set `KeepAliveTimeout` higher than the `5` seconds default value.

For example:

```
KeepAliveTimeout 300
```

You can find this property in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

goto W`HM->Service Configuration->PHP Configuration Editor` and update the value of `upload_max_filesize`.