# PHP File Upload Response

Tags: php, cordova, file-upload, xampp, server

I am sending a file to the server using phonegap filetransfer plugin. File Transfer plugin is showing transfer successful but when i checked my server no file is there. When i checked the response code it is showing the following:

```
Array(
[file]=>Array
(
 [name]=> hlc_parkingkanyakumari11-5-2015 1183232.db
 [type]=>
 [tmp_name]=>
 [error]=>1
 [size]=>0

)
)false
```

can anyone explain this error.My filesize is 4.1MB. I changed the upload_max_filesize to 10M but still this response is coming from the server.
i am testing it on my local server(XAMPP)

Comment: Have you restarted the server after you changed your php.ini settings?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4255650/1057527) might be the problem.

Comment: set set_time_limit(0); at the top of your page and try!!

Comment: no @machineaddict i restarted the system as well.

Comment: i tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 300) but no result @saty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your response. i found the solution of my problem. i checked the php error log, it was showing the following error

```
POST Content-Length of 4456596 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

Then i check post_max_size value in php.ini file. it was set to 3M which was lesser than the file size i was trying to transfer. I changed the value to 8M now it is working fine.