# jquery easyupload plugin not uploading pdf files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using easyupload jquery

Src: https://github.com/fater/jquery-easyupload

I am trying to upload files ( images,doc,docx uploaded perfectly) but pdf showing me error but its not explaning the error.

My CODE:

```html
elseif ($type == "upload_file") {
   $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin2/uploads/images/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   $uploadOk = 1;
   $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
   if (file_exists($target_file)) {$data['status'] = "error"; $data['msg'] = $BNL->msg("הקובץ עם השם הזה כבר קיים במערכת.");}
   elseif ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) {$data['status'] = "error"; $data['msg'] = $BNL->msg("המגבלה של העלאת קובץ היא 5MB");}
   elseif($imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx" ) {$data['status'] = "error"; $data['msg'] = $BNL->msg("הקבצים המותרים הם PDF, DOC, DOCX");}
   else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
     $data['msg'] = $BNL->msg("הקובץ ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " הועלה בהצלחה.", true);
     $_SESSION['file'] = basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    } else {
     //$data['msg'] = $BNL->msg("סליחה, הייתה בעיה בהעלאת הקובץ.");
     $data['msg'] = $_FILES['file']['error']; // Print "1"
    }
   }
   echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

I cant figure it out what the problem I am trying to fix it for two days.

Any one can help me please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Not yet, I want to check now but you can explain it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we need to check

`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

```
<?php
try {
    if (empty($_FILES)) {
        new \Exception('$_FILES array is empty.');
    } else {
        if (isset($_FILES['file']) && !empty($_FILES['file'])) {
            //Check error code
            #https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/File/Upload.php#L25
        };

    }

} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/File/Upload.php#L25

Read more: [$_FILE upload large file gives error 1 even though upload_max_size is bigger than the file size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4255617/5179786)

Comment: tried with the code you gave me and always getting "Exceeded filesize limit." even if the limit 9999999999999999 and the file sizing 4.2MB

Comment: Did you check the limit in your php.ini? Try with smaller file < 2MB.

Comment: ini_get('post_max_size'); response "8M"

Comment: How about `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, It's better to increase both of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686505/php-post-max-size-vs-upload-max-filesize-what-is-the-difference. Remember `post_max_size` needs to be greater than `upload_max_filesize `.